# PHP Convert % symbols from URL to actual url?

Tags: php

Ive got a script to handle some of my game files, For example the URL of them is like this:

```
 3%2C 2%2C 1%2C Smurf%21 My First Racing Game
```

Where the actual name should be:

```
3, 2, 1, Smurf! My First Racing Game
```

Is there a function to convert all them % things into the actual symbol they should be?

Or do i just have to str_replace them all?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is a URL-encoded string. You can use [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/urldecode) to decode it:

```
$str = '3%2C 2%2C 1%2C Smurf%21 My First Racing Game';
echo urldecode($str); // 3, 2, 1, Smurf! My First Racing Game
```

Answer (score 1):

php has a built in function for url decoding:

```
urldecode($yourUrlString)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Note:
if Your string is also [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded . This will work:

```
echo utf8_decode(urldecode(your url string));
```

Comment: Note that [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/utf8_decode) will convert UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 encoding, and will just throw away any characters that don't fit in the latter. If you want to _keep_ any Unicode characters, don't use utf8_decode(), but just keep the string in UTF-8 format and use the [mb_*()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) functions (or [preg_*()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) with the PCRE_UTF8 modifier) to manipulate it.